# Does $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(x - \mathtt{i}^\frac{2 k}{n+1}\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

This seems to be true:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(x - e^\frac{2\pi i k}{n+1} \right)$$

but I don't know how to demonstrate it, and definitely not neatly. I'd like to see why it should be (assuming it is).

The thing in particular that I don't really see, is what it is about the polynomial that makes this true (other than just doing the algebra, which I never find satisfactory).

Comment: The lhs is $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ for $x\neq 1$ in, and $i^{2k/(n+1)}=e^{ik\pi/(n+1)}$. Does it fit?

Comment: Makes sense, just didn't know how to get the left hand side.

Comment: I've worked it out now.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $x-1$ this is the same as saying $x^{n+1}-1=\prod_{k=0}^n (x-i^{\frac{2k}{n+1}})$

Comment: @Lucas And I hope your conclusion was that it is false.

Comment: @julien Have I made a typo here somewhere?

Comment: @julien Because I can't see it.

Comment: $i^{\frac{2k}{n+1}}$ isn't well-defined. There are $n+1$ different possible values for this expression in general.  But the real expression should be $i^{\frac{4k}{n+1}}$, where we take the value as being $e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n+1}}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OK, good point, too much time using computers :P